# can't give permissions to apps to access sdcard, I got the message "To protect your privacy, choose another folder"

Tags: external-sd, permissions, xiaomi

I'm trying to give access to the sdcard (like the stock file explorer), but if I try to select the root of the sdcard I get the message "To protect your privacy, choose another folder", and if select a folder it says it was not the correct folder and ask to give permissions again. The weird thing is that it was working at some point because I was able to create and delete folder at the sdcard, but now after trying again after several month I'm facing this issue...

I'm in a Xiaomi Poco X3 Pro (M2102J20SG), under miui global 13.0.8 with android 12, 2022-10-01 update, unrooted.

Comment: [*"You can no longer request access to the root directory of SD card"*](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#directory-access).